Flex container strangely places inner elements
I'm trying to make some slider with full width of page size. I`m trying to use some flex boxes.


.sliderContainer {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.sliderItem {
    width: 100vw;
    position: relative;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
<div class="sliderContainer">
     <div class="sliderItem">
          element
     </div>
     <div class="sliderItem">
          element
     </div>
</div>



In UI it looks something like this:
how it is shown
Moreover, if I change the value of overhidden to auto, the horizontall scroll bar won`t be in the left, but somewhere in the middle. here is an image: enter image description here
How should I properly place it?
I'm expecting the slider with size of whole page width. But now I've got some problems with placing that divs and giving them propriate css properties' values.
I've tried not to use the flexes, tried to manually scroll it and lots of more

try adding justify-content: start?

Do you want a horizontal slider or a vertical slider?

@huanfeng, It must be horizontal

@TanishqS , doesn`t work

Is this what you wanted?


.sliderContainer {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.sliderItem {
    width: 100vw;
    position: relative;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css">  
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="sliderContainer">
        <div class="sliderItem first-item" style="background-color: yellow;">
              element
        </div>
        <div class="sliderItem" style="background-color: green;">
              element
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="lib/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>




no, I do not need full height. My issue is shown in the attached images. The main problem is that my container is aligned not to the very left. In my example there are two items in flex container, each 100vw width. As so, there flex container's real content's width is 200% of screen width. And I expect the first element shown fully, and second one should be just pushed behind the right part of window. As for now it seems to overflow to both right and left and I see neither element fully

@huanfeng, your updated answer is getting the same bug the OP faces. The container automatically scrolls to the near-center the total scrollable  length

I thought that was what you expected...Updated the answer to remove the full height, is this you wanted?
